# Product of 9 consecutive numbers cannot be partitioned into two sets with equal product. Where is my flaw in the proof?

Tags: polynomials, divisibility, problem-solving

I have the following problem:

> Show that 9 consecutive integers cannot be partitioned into two sets such that the products of the first and second set are equal.

I know this question has been asked multiple times. Nearly all of the answers argue with prime factorization and I was just wondering where the flaw in my argumentation is:

Suppose such a partition exists. Then the product of the 9 consecutive integers needs to be a perfect square $n^2$. The product can also be represented as $k(k+1)\dots{}(k+8)$ which when multiplied out yields a polynomial of the form
$$
k^9 + \text{polynomial of degree} \leq 8.
$$
In order for this to be a perfect square, we would need to be able to represent the polynomial in the form $(\dots{})^2$. Since the degree of the polynomial is odd, we cannot do this and hence such a partition does not exist.

**Edit**: I know that there is a theorem (Erdos-Selfridge) that states the product of consecutive integers can never be a perfect power $x^l$. However, I was wondering if my argument about the even/odd property for this special case holds.

Comment: A non-square polynomial can still have square numbers as values.

Comment: @Karl Ok, I see. My argument only states that it cannot be square for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$ (because for this we would need the factorization which is impossible) but it could be the case that there exists a$k$ for which the polynomial would be square. Thus the problem lies in wrong use of $\forall, \exists$.

Comment: That sounds right, but how do you know the polynomial must factor as the square of a polynomial in order to always take square-number values? That's not obvious to me.

Comment: @user376343 Are you claiming $8^9$ is a perfect square? Because it is not.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni right, I made a typo, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: On a different direction, if two sets of numbers multiply to an equal product, it means they contain the same factors.  So that is to say if we work in reverse, starting with a given product, all the sets of integers that multiply to that product are obtainable from its prime factors.   For instance, for 24 we have 2 x 2 x 2 x 3.  If we find all partitionings of {2, 2, 2, 3}, the products of those partitions give us all the sets of integers whose product is 24.   So does there exist a number for which we can find 2 such sets such that between them they contain nine consecutive integers.

Comment: Before considering any maths, or even arithmetic, may we ask whether there is a flaw in your proof?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Consider two distinct questions about polynomials:

1. Can a polynomial of odd degree be a square of another polynomial?
2. Can a polynomial of odd degree take a value which is a square?

Your attempted proof depends on a negative answer to (2), but in fact (2) is true, for example $k^9+k^4+1$ is of odd degree, but when $k=2$ takes the value $529=23^2$.

Answer (score 13):

Instead of proving, more specific to the initial question why your approach does not hold. You write
$$
k(k+1)…(k+8)
$$
and then state that $k^9+\text{polynomial of degree}≤8$ cannot be a square because the degree is odd. But, you might also write
$$
k(k+1)…(k+7)(k+i)
$$
which is a polynomial with the same odd degree but you will certainly be able to find an $i$ for which the product is a square (i.e. $k(k+1)…(k+7)=(k+i)$). Not sequentially integers, but the claim was about the degree of the polynomial.

Even for a polynomial with odd degree one: $k+1$ will have many solutions so $k+1$ is a square.